# Performance of SignalR for high-frequency messaging

Tags: c#, performance, signalr

I am currently self-hosting a SignalR server in a WPF Application. In this application I need to call a method on the client at least 500 times per seconds. Right now I'm calling the method on the client side on each change. The CPU on the client side is way to high. The object I'm transferring contains about 20 base properties.

My requirement is that I cannot lose or skip any messages. But I can send the notifications as a list in bursts each second.

I'm not sure which is going to perform the best: short and fast or long and rare.

Comment: And how do you process those messages? Hopefully you put them in some kind of queue on the client side and process them in background?

Comment: Do all properties change each 'frame'?

Comment: @Evk I am currently processing the message on the client side directly. What queue mechanism would you propose?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, there are no "fake" notifications, which means that each object has one or more changes. But no, each property has not changed. I can manually write code to figure out which prop has change on the server side.

Comment: Why is it so necessary to put _( which might seems to be volatile)_ information on such a high rate?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen it is a monitoring system, each sensor changes value constantly.

Comment: And what is the client by the way? Javascript? Wpf as I understand is server in this case.

Comment: @Evk for now it is a WPF Application. It can be anything though.

Comment: If client is wpf application, what I mean is you can queue incoming messages and process them with another thread, not the same thread you receive them on. So if at some point you cannot process messages at the rate they come it - they will buffer in your in-memory queue, not in socket.

Comment: @Evk yes that is true, but i can only do so when the method is invoked. And if that happens to often it seems to interrupt the program flow overall.

Answer (score 1):

I would buffer the information serverside *(only storing changes)* and wait for the client to ask for new data. Each time the client asks for data, the server send the information in one packet *(binary)*. When the client finished processing the data, it asks for new data. This way you prevent writing too much data on the socket so it doesn't block. The length of the queue is an indication of the transport/processing of the client. When the queue grows too large *(serverside)* your network isn't fast enough or your client can't process that much data.

*I use this method on my software which is connected to a PLC sending current states of robot angles/positions*

---

Another way is using UDP, but it is lossy, so not very usefull in your situation.

Comment: I was hoping i could keep my notification based model one 100 percent. I bought the story about "real-time". No I am actually wondering if UDP/TCPIP is the way to go here as you mention...

Comment: The biggest problem with the notification model is, that you socket can be overflown and will block.

Comment: Yes. Also the problem with cyclic transmission is the overhead off polling dead values.